# range of possible values and model complexity

Tags: model-selection, aic, model-comparison, bic

I have a prediction model where the likelihood is a function of two components $(A,B)$

$L \sim \bf{A}^\alpha + \bf{B}^\beta$ ,

where both $\bf{A}$ and $\bf{B}$ are $n\times n$ matrices ($n$ is the number of regions, which will be meaningful below), and $\alpha, \beta$ are scalars. The parameters $\alpha, \beta$ and $\bf{B}$ are free parameters to be inferred, while $\bf{A}$ is fully defined and constant. I want to compare two models with different values of $\bf{B}$, using AIC or any similar criterion.

The question is about the number of free parameters in models, but there is one complication. The parameter $\bf{B}$ is a matrix encoding "whether or not two regions (out of $n$ regions) are in the same community". Hence, $\bf{B}$$_{ij}$ is $1$ if $i$ and $j$ are in the same community, and $0$ otherwise. The matrix $\bf{B}$, therefore, can be calculated from a $n$-dimensional vector $\bf{z}$, including community indices of regions, as follows

$B_{ij} = \delta(z_i, z_j)$ ,

where $\delta()$ is the Dirac delta function. By maximizing likelihood, I infer community assignment of regions ($z_i$) and scalars $\alpha, \beta$.

Thus, if I have two models with different number of communities, only part that is changing is the range of possible values of $z_i$. For instance, for a model with 2 communities, $z_i$ can have values of $1,2$, and values of $1,2,3,4,5$ for five communities.

Q1. Is the number of free parameters always $n+2$ (2 is for $\alpha, \beta$), regardless of the number of communities?

Q2. Is there any model selection criterion which incorporates possible ranges of parameters? My intuition is that as I increase the range of $z_i$, the stability of the model should get worse, I'm not sure.

Comment: What do you mean by $\bf{A}^\alpha + \bf{B}^\beta$ ?  A in power of $\alpha$ plus B in power of $\beta$?

Comment: Sorry for the ambiguity. Yes, it means power of, but it is for every individual element of the matrix; nothing fancy with matrix power etc.